# Recovery files from a damage VM?

Tags: windows-xp, vmware-fusion

After search and search again, my VM still can't recovery. Does somebody know how to retrieve the files from the VM?
My VM is XP, it can't boot up anymore after my forced quit. In the Mac OS 10.6.2, I try to "get info" the VM file, I can see it is still using 25G space. I try to mount it with VMDK mounter (just right click the VM file and chose open with), it can mount but nothing inside. I also try to use filesalvage to recovery the files after mounted the VM, it can recovery many many files, but the files name and some document become to be symbol. What can I do now? Pls help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar experience where my host os crashed and afterwards my wndows xp guest wouldn't boot due to filesystem corruption. I was using virtualbox but you can probably do this with vmware too.

To recover, i added the crashed vm file as a second disk in a working windows xp vm. Boot up the working version and do a chkdisk on the newly added drive. You might also want to try booting from your windows xp install disk and run system repair.

Comment: This works in other VM environments too.  I maintain an ESX cluster and keep a "utility" VM around just to attach other VM's disks to just in case.